# is there a way to do > public void test<A,B,C,....,Z>(...)

Tags: c#

i try to create a method to build fast DataTable
my current code is like this

implementation

```
var table = build("myTableName").col<int>("col1").col<string>("col2")
.row(1, "row1")
.row(2, "row2");

public static DataTable build(string name)
{
 return new DataTable(name);
}

public static DataTable col<T>(this DataTable table, string name)
{
 table.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(T));
 retun table;
}

public static DataTable row(this DataTable table, params object[] objects)
{
 DataRow row = table.NewRow();
 int i = 0;           
 objects.ToList().ForEach(obj => row[i++] = obj ?? DBNull.Value);
 table.Rows.Add(row);

 return table;
}
```

i could make things faster if there's a way to do multiple type arguments.
such as

```
public static col<A,B,C, ...>col(params string[] names){...}
```

Comment: Why gave this a -1? This is a good question, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can make multiple type arguments, but you would have to make an explicit overload for each number of columns you have to support.

In my opinion, doing this would not be good idea. It *might* enable you to write this code some fractions of a second faster, but I think it would be much harder to read. Readability is important - code is generally read a lot more often than it is written.

Comment: Thanks. i use to get that commenta lot. my colleague use to say my ocde is hard to read. but for me i thought specifying col<>() and row() is much more readable than regular method. since the code is much shorter, so it's much more understanable.... but my colleague not quite agree with me :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish this is by creating an overload for every number of parameters, so one `col<T>`, one `col<T1, T2>` and so forth.

The .NET framework does the same thing. For example, `Func<T>` has 17 versions for just this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just using the type as a parameter in another method call, wouldn't this work:

```
public static DataTable cols(this DataTable table, string[] names, Type[] types)
{
    for(...)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(names[i], types[i]); 
    }
    return table;
}

.cols(new string[] {"col1", "col2"}, new Type[] {typeof(int), typeof(string)})
```

Not pretty, and there's many ways to improve over "pass and iterate 2 arrays, hope they're the same size", but that's the general idea.  Do some checking and maybe use a struct to pass your data in, should work out ok.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static DataTable col<T1>(this DataTable table, string name1)
{
    table.Columns.Add(name1, typeof(T1));
    return table;
}

public static DataTable col<T1, T2>(this DataTable table, string name1, string name2)
{
    table.Columns.Add(name1, typeof(T1));
    table.Columns.Add(name2, typeof(T2));
    return table;
}

public static DataTable col<T1, T2, T3>(this DataTable table, string name1, string name2, string name 3)
{
    table.Columns.Add(name1, typeof(T1));
    table.Columns.Add(name2, typeof(T2));
    table.Columns.Add(name3, typeof(T3));
    return table;
}
```

Then finally:

```
public static DataTable cols(this DataTable table, Type[] types, string[] names)
{
    // ...
}
```